# SQL Sum table with fixed rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I've got a query that I want to give a fixed table output (So I can graph in Excel easier).
The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 

Case

WHEN ScrapsReasonID = 2339 THEN 'Box 5'

WHEN ScrapsReasonID = 2340 THEN 'Box 6'

WHEN ScrapsReasonID = 2342 THEN 'Box 7'

WHEN ScrapsReasonID = 2343 THEN 'Box 8'

WHEN ScrapsReasonID = 2344 THEN 'Box 9'

Else 'Unknown'

END 

AS 'BoxNumber',

count(Case When PartNumberID = '378' Then Scraps End) AS '9.5mm',

count(Case When PartNumberID = '379' Then Scraps End) AS '10.0mm',

count(Case When PartNumberID = '380' Then Scraps End) AS '10.5mm'


FROM [ProcessControl].[dbo].[OutputScrap]

WHERE 

MachineId = '93'

And ScrapsReasonID In

(
'2339',
'2340',
'2342',
'2343',
'2344'
)

And PDate Between '22-may-2014' and '29-may-2014'

GROUP BY ScrapsReasonID
```

This works if there is definitely all 5 scrapreasonIDs between the set dates, but if there are only 3 for instance I only get 3 rows in the Sum table. Is there a way of always returning all 5 scrapreasonIDs and zero values for the 9.5, 10.0, 10.5 if they don't exist?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: It is sql-server i guess you should tag your question properly

Comment: Removed the mysql tag and added the sql-server tag because the syntax clearly suggests SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `left outer join` instead of the `case` statement.  In addition, I'm making the following changes:

- Changing the `count()` to `sum()`.  It seems more reasonable to want to sum the values in a field called `scraps, although I might be wrong.
- Added `Else 0` to the conditional aggregations.  I'm assuming you want `0` when there are no matches rather than `NULL`.
- Removed the condition on ScrapsReasonID.  The `join` does the necessary filtering.
- Moved the remaining conditions to the `on` clause, so the `where` doesn't turn the outer join into an inner join.
- Removed the single quotes for the column names.  For SQL Server, use square braces (I am assuming SQL Server because of the three-part table naming convention).
- Changed the date format to the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Here is the resulting query

```
SELECT bn.BoxNumber,
       SUM(Case When PartNumberID = '378' Then Scraps Else 0 End) AS [9.5mm],
       SUM(Case When PartNumberID = '379' Then Scraps Else 0 End) AS [10.0mm],
       SUM(Case When PartNumberID = '380' Then Scraps Else 0 End) AS [10.5mm]
FROM (SELECT 2339 as ScrapsReasonID, 'Box 5' as BoxNumber UNION ALL
      SELECT 2340, 'Box 6' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2342, 'Box 7' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2343, 'Box 8' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2344, 'Box 9' 
     ) bn LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [ProcessControl].[dbo].[OutputScrap] os
     ON os.ScrapsReasonID = bn.ScrapsReasonID AND
        os.MachineId = '93' AND
        os.PDate Between '2014-05-22' and '2014-05-29'
GROUP BY bn.BoxNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very close to working, I removed the where statement and put the criteria into the on statement to prevent further filtering and it now works.
     ) bn LEFT JOIN
     [ProcessControl].[dbo].[OutputScrap] os
     ON os.ScrapsReasonID = bn.ScrapsReasonID 
     AND PDate Between '2014-05-22' 
     AND '2014-05-29' 
     AND MachineId = '93'